# javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola amigos tengo un detalle que no logro resolver. Ya llevo varias horas y no veo mi error.

El error me lo arroja en esta parte

```
var p = document.getElementById(obj1[ind]);.
```

No se que estoy olvidando o es algo que no estoy viendo.

El error que me arroja es

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

```
        function actualizaEtiquetasGeneralMicelanea() {
            for (var i = 39; i < 48; i++) {
                getDatosEtiquetasPorMicelanea(i);
            }

            //Jhonford - agrupado de EEC
            //getDatosEtiquetasPorMicelanea(i);
        }
        function getDatosEtiquetasPorMicelanea(claArea) {
            $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                url: "GrupoLineasEmbobinados.aspx/getDatosEtiquetasEmbobinadoDatos",
                data: '{claArea:"' + claArea + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.d.datos != null && response.d.datos.length == 4) {
                        var obj1 = null;

                        if (claArea == 39) {
                            obj1 = ["MetaTurnoLembMicelanea", "MetaAcumLemMicelanea", "ProdAcumLemMicelanea", "CumLemMicelanea"];
                        }
                                                else if (claArea == 40) {
                                                    obj1 = ["Polylemb1_MetaTurno", "Polylem1_MetaAcum", "Polylemb1_ProdAcum", "Polylemb1_Cumplimiento"];
                                                }
                                               else if (claArea == 41) {
                                                   obj1 = ["Lembobinadopoly2_MetaTurno", "Lembobinadopoly2_MetaAcum", "Lembobinadopoly2_ProdAcum", "Lembobinadopoly2_Cumplimiento"];
                                                }
                                                else if (claArea == 42) {
                                                    obj1 = ["Evapslemb_MetaTurno", "Evapslemb_MetaAcum", "Evapslemb_ProdAcum", "Evapslemb_Cumplimiento"];
                                                }
                                                else if (claArea == 47) {
                                                    obj1 = ["319nema48_meta_turno", "319nema48_meta_acumulada", "319nema48_produccion_acumulada", "319nema48_cumplimiento"];
                                                }
            

                        for (var ind = 0; ind < 4; ind++) {
                            var p = document.getElementById(obj1[ind]);----error en esta parte------
                            //alert(response.d.datos[ind]);
                            
                            if (ind != 3) {
                                p.innerHTML = response.d.datos[ind];
                            }
                            else {
                                p.innerHTML = response.d.datos[ind] + '%';
                            }

                            //cambioDeColor en funcion del porcentaje
                            var boton = document.getElementById(obj1[3]);
                            if (response.d.datos[3] <= 92) {//valor indicado por cintia
                                boton.className = "btn btn-secondary my-2 claseRangoInCumplimiento";
                            }
                            else {
                                boton.className = "btn btn-secondary my-2";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //alert(textStatus + ": " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Qué id tiene `obj1[ind]`? Qué tipo de objeto es?

Comment: `var obj1 = null;` Esta inicializandose como NULL, pero no hay nada que contenga el caso de que el valor sea NULL. Es decir, que si llega a obtener el valor NULL, te caerá el error.

Comment: Veo que tienes 5 condiciones que cargan `obj1` ... pero, estas segura que al menos una de ellas se cumple ??? Y que pasa si el objeto sigue siendo NULL, ¿Como lo resuelves?

Comment: Quiere decir que tu `obj1` es `null`, te oriento... primero lo declaras `var obj1 = null;`  luego esperas bajo cierta condición inicializarlo, el problema es que el valor de `claArea` no entra en ninguna de tus condicionales, y se queda en `null`, por lo tanto al llegar a tu bucle `for` cuando hace `obj1[0]` estas haciendo `null[0]` entonces eso te arroja error, y tú dirás pero yo me aseguro de que al llamar la función estoy enviando los valores de las condiciones, para que veas que pasa en esta Petición Ajax cuando la ejecutas puedes pintar `console.log(obj1)` antes del `for`.

Comment: También puedes probar cambiando el parámetro de `async: true,`  a `async: false` para que tu primer `for` dentro de `actualizaEtiquetasGeneralMicelanea()` espere a que se complete la petición.

Comment: Hola que tal gracias por responder. Si de echo las 5 condiciones cargan los datos de manera correcta. Pero el error me aparece en la consola de Google.. Por lo que, por algo me manda ese error.. De echo al usuario le aparecen los datos de manera correcta, pero quiero resolver ese error..

Comment: Pero @NoéTorres, las condicionales cargan en caso de... pero en el caso de NULO, no tienes contemplado nada. Entonces al momento de caer un nulo, tu codigo falla

Comment: ok ok gracias por sus respuestas.. Y alguna idea de que debo hacer para resolverlo? Y de antemano gracias otra vez..

Comment: Controla la excepción en caso de `NULL`... debe haber algún dato base, o que `obj1` no dependa de `claArea`. O debe haber un dato que siempre se inicialice. Por ejemplo, si el valor por defecto de `claArea` es 39, ese debería ser el valor por defecto de `obj1`

Comment: Gracias a todos por la Orientación. Ya lo resolví, les agradezco mucho..

Comment: Comparte tu resultado o que realizaste, como lo resolviste ;)

Comment: Si claro. en un rato mas, estaré publicando como lo resolví,ayer ya no me dio tiempo. Por si alguien mas le sale el mismo error. Saludos..

Comment: Y se quedó sin respuesta esta pregunta. Lástima.